# My discord.py edited cooldown doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.7, discord.py

I tried to change the lib (`core.py`) and changed the cooldown command to this so all commands will share 1 cooldown, for example after using `!hi`, also `!bye` would have been cooldowned instead of only `!hi`:

```
def shared_cooldown(rate, per, type=BucketType.default):
    cooldown = Cooldown(rate, per, type=BucketType.default)
    def decorator(func):
        if isinstance(func, Command):
            func._buckets = CooldownMapping(cooldown)
        else:
            func.__commands_cooldown__ = cooldown
        return func
    return decorator
```

Instead of this:

```
def cooldown(rate, per, type=BucketType.default):
    """A decorator that adds a cooldown to a :class:`.Command`
    or its subclasses.

    A cooldown allows a command to only be used a specific amount
    of times in a specific time frame. These cooldowns can be based
    either on a per-guild, per-channel, per-user, or global basis.
    Denoted by the third argument of ``type`` which must be of enum
    type ``BucketType`` which could be either:

    - ``BucketType.default`` for a global basis.
    - ``BucketType.user`` for a per-user basis.
    - ``BucketType.guild`` for a per-guild basis.
    - ``BucketType.channel`` for a per-channel basis.
    - ``BucketType.member`` for a per-member basis.
    - ``BucketType.category`` for a per-category basis.

    If a cooldown is triggered, then :exc:`.CommandOnCooldown` is triggered in
    :func:`.on_command_error` and the local error handler.

    A command can only have a single cooldown.

    Parameters
    ------------
    rate: :class:`int`
        The number of times a command can be used before triggering a cooldown.
    per: :class:`float`
        The amount of seconds to wait for a cooldown when it's been triggered.
    type: ``BucketType``
        The type of cooldown to have.
    """

    def decorator(func):
        if isinstance(func, Command):
            func._buckets = CooldownMapping(Cooldown(rate, per, type))
        else:
            func.__commands_cooldown__ = Cooldown(rate, per, type)
        return func
    return decorator
```

In my bot code I added this line: `my_cooldown = commands.shared_cooldown(1, 600, commands.shared_cooldown)` And 2 commands:

```
@bot.command(name ="hi")
@my_cooldown
async def hi(ctx):
    site = ["https://google.com", "https://youtube.com"]
    chosen = random.choice(site)
    url = chosen
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Your site", description=f"[Click Here]({url})", color=0x00ff00)
    if ctx.message.guild == None:
        await ctx.author.send('You can not use this command in your DM!')
        pass
    else:
        await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command(name ="bye")
@my_cooldown
async def bye(ctx):
    site = ["https://google.com", "https://youtube.com"]
    chosen = random.choice(site)
    url = chosen
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Your site", description=f"[Click Here]({url})", color=0x00ff00)
    if ctx.message.guild == None:
        await ctx.author.send('You can not use this command in your DM!')
        pass
    else:
        await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
```

Now, the problem is my cooldown works for all commands, but ALL users gets cooldowned if ONE PERSON uses the command. I tried changing `def shared_cooldown(rate, per, type=BucketType.default):
    cooldown = Cooldown(rate, per, type=BucketType.default)` to `def shared_cooldown(rate, per, type=BucketType.user):
    cooldown = Cooldown(rate, per, type=BucketType.user)`, but then people got cooleddown for only the one command they used, instead of all commands. How can I make it cooldown only the user who used the command instead of EVERYONE, but still cooldown all the commands for that one user?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we have to force the commands to always share a `CooldownMapping` object.  That's pretty easy, but it means that the decorator has to go outside the `command`decorator, since we can't attach the cooldown to the function anymore and rely on the `command` machinery to generate the mapping.

```
def shared_cooldown(rate, per, type=BucketType.default):
    cooldown = Cooldown(rate, per, type=type)
    cooldown_mapping = CooldownMapping(cooldown)
    def decorator(func):
        if isinstance(func, Command):
            func._buckets = cooldown_mapping 
        else:
            raise ValueError("Decorator must be applied to command, not the function")
        return func
    return decorator
```

This snuck through because the default bucket type stores all of its information in the cooldown itself.  The more granular buckets store the information in the mapping, which was being created anew every time.  I actually check the different bucket types when I wrote the original, but because there's only one of me I didn't notice that it was actually using the default bucket every time.

```
my_cooldown = shared_cooldown(1, 600, BucketType.User)  # Pass the desired bucket type

@my_cooldown  # shared cooldown has to go first now 
@bot.command(name ="bye")
async def bye(ctx):
    ...
```